# Warum wird Vergangenheit in Präsens übersetzt „Hat der Zoo mittwochs geöffnet?“

Tags: grammatical-case, tense

Warum heißt das gegenwärtig kontinuierlich? Könnte diese Konstruktion in jedem Fall mit der Vergangenheit + Genitivzeit funktionieren?

> Hat der Zoo mittwochs geöffnet?
>
> Is the zoo open on Wednesdays?

Comment: Das sieht zwar aus wie Vergangenheit (Perfekt), ist aber keine.

Comment: @tofro Warum benutzt es dann das Verb hat?

Comment: @user5389726598465 Wegen _geöffnet **haben**_.

Comment: Das ist ein tricky Beispiel. "haben" ist hier kein Hilfsverb, sondern Vollverb. Und "geöffnet" wird hier als Adjektiv verwendet. "Der Laden hat offen", "der Laden hat auf", "der Laden ist auf", "der Laden hat geöffnet"

Comment: @tofro Ich wär mir nicht so sicher, ob 'haben' hier nicht doch so etwas wie ein Hilfsverb oder ein Zwischending ist, es hat ja eine kopula-ähnliche Funktion. Möglicherweise ist das irgendwann mal aus dem Perfekt entstanden: Wir haben den Laden geöffnet. Es gibt dafür nur keine grammatische Bezeichnung, das ist sozusagen das einzige Problem. Den Absentiv (er ist joggen) gibt's ja wohl auch noch nicht so sehr lange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hat der Zoo Mittwochs geöffnet? – Der Zoo hat Mittwochs geöffnet.
>
> Ist der Zoo Mittwochs geöffnet? – Der Zoo ist Mittwochs geöffnet.
>
> Wird der Zoo Mittwochs geöffnet? – Der Zoo wird Mittwochs geöffnet.

Teuflisch: Alle drei Satzpaare *können* genau dasselbe bedeuten.

In allen drei Fällen handelt es sich um das Passiv. Wäre es Aktiv, würde *öffnen* ein Objekt verlangen, das geöffnet wird. Geöffnet wird jedoch das Subjekt, der Zoo!

Comment: *Der Zoo ist geöffnet.* ist Zustandspassiv. *Der Zoo hat geöffnet.* ist die umgangssprachliche Variante.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht. Ich glaube auch nicht, dass das umgangssprachlich ist. Duden nennt "Der Laden hat auf" und "der Laden hat offen" (was dasselbe ist, aber kein Passiv sein kann) weder umgangssprachlich noch Passiv

Comment: Seit wann sind *auf* und *offen* Partizipien?

Comment: Das habe ich nicht behauptet

Comment: Gut, dann eben andersherum: Sieht man *geöffnet* als Partizip in Adjektivfunktion, würde es im Satz *Der Zoo ist geöffnet.* als Adverb eingesetzt, entsprechend einem echten Adjektiv im Satz *Der Zoo ist schön.* Es würde hingegen niemand *Der Zoo **hat** schön.* sagen, was deiner Adjektivthese entgegensteht.

Comment: Dann nimm "hat offen" als Beweis der Adjektivthese. Es dürfte unstrittig sein, das "offen" und "geöffnet" hier Synonyme sind. Wogegen ich mich bei deiner Antwort nur verwehre ist, dass "hat geöffnet" Zustandspassiv sei. Alles andere passt schon. Zum letzten Satz deiner Antwort: Nein. Der Zoo ist sowohl Subjekt als auch Objekt der Handlung. Er hat sich ja (als Organisation, sozusagen)selber aufgemacht.

Comment: *Der Zoo hat Mittwochs den Zoo geöffnet.* ist nun aber wieder Perfekt aktiv, was ja die Eingangsfrage war. (Einzig das *Mittwochs* stört noch.)

Comment: Das ist richtig, aber was anderes als "Der Zoo hat mittwochs geöffnet", was die Eingangsfrage war ;)

Comment: Du hast gerade geschrieben, dass der Zoo sowohl das Subjekt als auch das Objekt des Originalsatzes sei. Das ist er eben nicht. Der Originalsatz hat kein Objekt. Nur ein Subjekt.

Comment: Lustig lustig tralalalala, vor allem das 'der Zoo hat mittwochs den Zoo geöffnet'. N'Bier wär jetzt nicht schlecht...

Comment: @Janka: Dass es sich um eine passivische Konstruktionsart handelt, weil (mit) dem Subjekt etwas geschieht, ist ein gutes Argument. Es gibt allerdings so viele Passiv-Varianten, dass man sich fragen kann, was überhaupt ein Passiv ist. Das Fehlen eines Agens ist aber sicherlich ein entscheidendes Passiv-Merkmal, dann wären solche Sätze eine zusätzliche Passiv-Variante. Aber Zustandspassiv? Gut, es ist ein Zustand. Übrigens, 'öffnen' muss nicht obligatorisch ein Objekt haben: Wir öffnen um 8, und dann bleibt unser Geschäft bis 22 Uhr geöffnet.

Comment: Der zweite Satz mit *sein* ist auch grammatisch als Zustandspassiv erkennbar. Darin kann man dann auch das Partizip als Adjektiv/Adverb deuten, es passt grammatisch. Allerdings gibt es das Adjektiv *offen*, warum sollte man also das Partizip verwenden? Der erste Satz mit dem Hilfsverb *haben* ist in jedem Fall eine Varietät des zweiten.

Comment: Wenn man daran glaubt, dann ist das so. Ich meinerseits glaube nicht, dass alles, was sich an Sprache beobachten lässt, rückstandslos in grammatische Beschreibung aufgelöst werden kann. Wenn hier 'hat geöffnet' als eine Varietät von 'ist geöffnet' anzusehen ist, wäre die Frage, um was für eine Varietät es sich handelt: eine regionale, oder soziale, oder diachrone, oder eine noch andere? Ist 'sie hat den Mund halb geöffnet' aus 'ihr Mund ist halb geöffnet' auch so ein Quasi-Zustandspassiv? Was ist damit letztlich gewonnen, wenn man 'hat geöffnet' in irgendeiner Kategorie untergebracht hat?

Comment: Ich habe lediglich versucht, die Frage zu beantworten. Die naheliegendste Erklärung ist, dass, wie so oft, die Sprecher es mit *haben* und *sein* nicht so genau nehmen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich vermute, es gibt noch andere derartige - wahrscheinlich umgangssprachliche - Verkürzungen:

> der Knopf ist ab < ist abgegangen
>
> wir haben heute nichts auf < vom Lehrer als Hausaufgabe aufbekommen
>
> hast du dein Wörterbuch mit? < mitgenommen und jetzt dabei (in meiner Region sagt man auch 'hast du das Buch bei?')

Sind also diese verkürzten Sätze eigentlich ein verdecktes Perfekt? Oder sind auch die Langversionen kein 'richtiges Perfekt'? Es gibt in der Tat auch viele andere Fälle mit konjugiertem 'haben' und einem Partizip 2, die nicht als Perfekt zu verstehen sind:

> er arbeitet von morgens bis abends und hat dabei das Fenster geöffnet
>
> sie hat seit einer Woche ihr Konto gesperrt und kommt jetzt nicht ohne weiteres an ihr Geld, ihr war nämlich die Brieftasche gestohlen worden
>
> er hat bei sich schon jahrelang den Strom abgestellt
>
> sie hat auf dem Foto den Mund halb geöffnet.

Manche solcher Sätze sind grenzwertig. Aber auch das Perfekt selbst ist oft grenzwertig:

> sie hat ihr Auto jetzt wieder repariert und kann damit wieder zur Arbeit fahren.

Das wird wegen dem 'jetzt' vermutlich heißen, dass sie selbst es nicht wieder in Gang gebracht hat, sondern dass es, nachdem es eine Weile kaputt war, jetzt wieder funktionstüchtig im Hof und 'von irgendwem repariert' zur Benutzung bereitsteht, dass es jetzt wieder repariert **ist**. Und heißt *er hat das schon erledigt* nicht vor allem, dass es jetzt erledigt **ist** und sich niemand mehr darum zu kümmern braucht, ebenso wie die Information, dass *der Brief angekommen ist* so ziemlich dasselbe bedeutet wie *der Brief ist da*?

Manchen lässt es keine Ruhe, dass solche Zwischenwesen wie 'die Bank hat geöffnet' nicht in irgendeiner Schublade unterzubringen sind, von denen es doch schon so viele gibt bis hin zum Zustandspassiv im Konjunktiv des doppelten Futur 2 (werde geöffnet gewesen gewesen sein - wobei die doppelt zusammengesetzten Zeiten à la 'ich für mein Teil hatte die Sache schon abgehakt gehabt' nicht allgemein anerkannt sind). Wie wäre es für diese Perfekt-Präsens-Zwitter mit 'Schein-Perfekt'?

Comment: Schön. Wirklich. Nur keine Antwort ;) Bin aber vollständig mit dir einig.

Comment: @tofro: Die Frage ist für mich so unverständlich, dass ich auf sie beim besten Willen nicht antworten kann. Was wollte der Dichter damit sagen, ging es nicht um diese merkwürdigen Perfekte, die eigentlich keine Perfekte sind?

Answer (score 1):

Ein Partizip Perfekt im Deutschen kann die Funktion eines Adjektivs übernehmen. Dabei können Sätze entstehen, die aussehen wie Perfekt, aber tatsächlich im Präsens stehen:

> Der Zoo hat Mittwochs geöffnet

Ist eigentlich Präsens (kann aber auch Perfekt sein, das hängt vom Kontext ab), das Partizip ist hier als ein Adjektiv verwendet.

Es lässt sich leichter verstehen, wenn man Formen nimmt, die im Präsens ein anderes Hilfsverb als im Perfekt verwenden:

> Der Zoo ist Mittwochs geöffnet
>
> Die Pistole ist geladen

man kann auch sagen

> Der Zoo hat Mittwochs offen

oder

> Der Zoo hat Mittwochs auf

und dein Beispielsatz ist eine Mischung aus beiden.

Comment: ... _hat mittwochs geöffnet_ kann nicht Perfekt sein, wegen dem 's' hinten an 'mittwochs'.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Versteh' ich nicht. "Früher hat der Laden immer mittwochs geöffnet, jetzt macht er donnerstags auf". Das ist für mich perfektes Perfekt.

Comment: Interessant, nur: Da stand kein 'früher'. Ist aber albern, sich über sowas zu streiten, im Grunde meinst Du ja dasselbe oder jedenfalls etwas sehr ähnliches wie ich.

Comment: Beim letzten Beispiel kann man „hat auf“ als trennbares Verb ansehen. „Aufhaben“ ist im Duden mit der Bedeutung „geöffnet haben“ drin. „Offenhaben“ und „geöffnethaben“ gibt es aber wahrscheinlich nicht ...

Answer (score 1):

> Der Zoo hat mittwochs geöffnet

beschreibt eine Eigenschaft des Zoos genau wie

> Der Zoo hat tausend Tiere

Indem du sagst

> Hat der Zoo mittwochs geöffnet?

verwandelst du lediglich den Aussagesatz in einen Fragesatz, mit Perfekt hat das in diesem Fall nichts zu tun.

Wie tofro richtig bemerkt, spielt das Partizip Perfekt »geöffnet« hier die Rolle eines Adjektivs, man nennt das »attributiver Gebrauch«, der u. a. bei transitiven, passivfähigen Verben wie »öffnen« möglich ist ([Quelle](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&q=partizip%20perfekt#v=snippet&q=attributiver%20gebrauch%20das%20in%20den%20Wald%20gelaufene%20Kind&f=false)).

Answer (score 0):

> Hat der Zoo Mittwochs geöffnet?

Ja, die Konstruktion funktioniert einwandfrei.

Könntest Du bitte genauer erläutern, was genau Du mit *"Vergangenheit+Genitivzeit"* meinst?
Ich bin kein Grammatik-Experte, aber der Grund warum die Frage *gegenwärtig kontinuierlich* gestellt wird, ist das sie sich auf ***Mittwochs*** (alle zukünftigen und vergangenen *Mittwoche*) im Allgemeinen bezieht.

Wenn ein ganz ***bestimmter Mittwoch*** gemeint ist, würde man fragen:

> Hat der Zoo **nächsten** Mittwoch geöffnet?
>
> Is the zoo open on **next** Wednesday?

oder

> Hat der Zoo am Mittwoch den **16.05.** geöffnet?
>
> Is the zoo open on Wednesday the **05/16**?

Comment: Es ist nicht Mittowchs, die mich verwirrt. Ich verstehe nicht, hat geöffnet, was auf Englisch bedeutet  "has opened", während die Bedeutung Präsens ist

Comment: @user5389726598465 Die Bedeutung des von Dir exemplarisch angeführten Satzes ist: _"Is the zoo always open(ed) on Wednesdays."_ for very literal translation. The meaning is _presence_, and that's just fine.